# How to see the video bit rate of an AVI file

Tags: video, encoding, avi, mencoder, bitrate

I'm trying to add subtitles to an AVI file while minimizing loss in video quality. I can adjust the quality by setting the bitrate in mencoder. I would like to know the bitrate of the original file in order to set this correctly. How can I find out the original bitrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg -i somefile.avi outfile.avi should spit the bitrate to the command line

ffplay will spit out the bitrate too

Comment: Why is an output file name needed?

Comment: see the edit...ffmpeg is a transcoder ffplay is a player

Comment: and it isn't required to get it to spit out the bitrate it's just a habit

Comment: If I leave out the output file name then it shows the information. If I give an output file name then it starts creating that file.

Comment: yeah...it's a does that ctl-c should stop it

Comment: but it still outputs bitrate to the terminal before it starts transcoding

Comment: What is it creating? Is it just making an exact copy of the input file?

Comment: just a junk file you don't need